# Get rid of lingering partition

Tags: macos, finder, partition

Not sure what happened, but when I was setting up my new Mac, something wonky happened w/ the second partition. I ended up deleting it and naming the second partition on my laptop *Machintosh HD 3*.

It's working great, but every time I log in now, */Volumes/Machintosh HD 2* appears with a fresh *Library* directory. How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 2):

I would use the terminal to sort things out if you don't see what's happened in Disk Utility.

```
diskutil list
```

From there, you can see all the names and numbers OS X has given to the volumes/partitions. Eject them all (except for the booted OS). `diskutil eject disk2s2` etc...

At that point, you might need to clean up the bad mount points.

```
ls -l /Volumes
```

At this point you want to be sure you're not deleting actual files so if you're not comfortable using `rm` in terminal, you can use the Finder. Use the Go menu to **Go to Folder...** and enter /Volumes

Rename the Macintosh HD to something like **temp** and then move all the bad mount points to the trash and rename your boot volume to be what you wish. Now when you mount the drives the name should match what you have in Disk Utility.

Comment: I've tried deleting */Volumes/Macintosh HD 2*, but when I reboot the computer or logout/login, OSX puts it back :O The OS does this, yet there is no */Volumes/Macintosh HD 2* in Disk Utility.

Comment: @quickshiftin OK. If you disconnect all external drives and then use Finder to rename all the drives: one, two, three, etc... What happens when you reboot and type `ls -l /Volumes` in terminal?

Comment: Finder doesn't even show *Machintosh HD 2*, only *Macintosh HD* and *Machitosh HD 3*. I can see *Macintosh HD 2* in */Volumes* from Terminal. Also like I said, deleting it is of no use, as OSX puts it back after a fresh login.

Comment: If you cannot rename the volumes, you might need to make a full backup and then boot into recovery mode and let Disk Utility repair the drive and then help with renaming the partitions.

Comment: I've been in recovery mode. It's just as oblivious to *Macintosh HD 2* as when I use it from a logged in user.